# Dependency Issue with Razor using a Package Deploy on Azure's Cloud Service

Tags: razor, azure, azure-web-roles

I'm trying to deploy the RockPaperAzure project out to an Azure cloud service but I am getting this error.

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.
```

Everything I found searching for a solution just suggested including the .ddl files in the project and referencing those .dlls, but that did not work.

I have no clue what is missing.

EDIT: I fixed the issue by upgrading the framework to ASP.NET MVC 4.

Answer (score 3):

You have dependent assemblies referencing an old verion - 1.0 - Use NuGet to update all your references.  Failing that, you can add an assembly binding redirect to the web.config:

```
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    ...
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages.Razor" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

Just make sure you are referencing the version that is deployed in the bin folder.

Comment: I tried this, but I fixed the issue by upgrading the framework to ASP.NET MVC 4.